# jQuery Body CSS Background URL if Empty Random URL

Tags: jquery, css, background

I am trying to see if in the CSS on the page the body style background does not have anything in the URL to then fade in and out an array of images.

This is my code but It does not appear to do anything or throw any errors

```
    <style>
html {

}
body
{
    background-color: transparent;
    background: url([%MEDIA_URL%]) no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size: cover;
}
@media (max-width: 1024px) {
    html {
        background: url([%MEDIA_URL%]) no-repeat center center fixed;
        background-size: cover;
        height: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    body
    {
        background-color: transparent;
        background: none;
        height:100%;
        overflow: scroll;
        -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    }
}
</style>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    if ($('body').css("background") === 'url()') {

        (function($) { 

            var bgImageArray = ['exterior.jpg', 'chairs.jpg', 'entrance-logo.jpg'],
            base = "http://stage.houstonian.com/resources/1/BG_Images/",
            secs = 6;
            bgImageArray.forEach(function(img){
                new Image().src = base + img; 
                // caches images, avoiding white flash between background replacements
            });

            function backgroundSequence() {
            console.log('url(' + base + bgImageArray[0] +')');
                window.clearTimeout();
                var k = 0;
                for (i = 0; i < bgImageArray.length; i++) {
                    setTimeout(function(){ 
                        $('body').css({
                    'background': "url(" + base + bgImageArray[k] + ")"
                });
                    if ((k + 1) === bgImageArray.length) { setTimeout(function() { backgroundSequence() }, (secs * 1000))} else { k++; }            
                    }, (secs * 1000) * i)   
                }
            }
            backgroundSequence();  

        }(jQuery));

    }
});
</script>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. The array of background images i got from this working fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/sm1215/r5or5w6m/3/

Would be nice to make it random too :)

Comment: Also the [%MEDIA_URL%] is a tag used by the CMS and does not show if no image was uploaded for the page.

Comment: You know you can quite easily [**test things like this**](https://jsfiddle.net/u7qp883m/) yourself, and see that it probably never will return the string `url()` ?

Comment: test if `$('body').css("background-image") == 'none'`

Comment: Why does it not return the url string? Is it possible to do this? The fiddle works for css background.

Comment: But in the fiddle, do you see the string `'url()'` in the console? Even just setting that CSS property won't return that string ... ever -> https://jsfiddle.net/u7qp883m/1/

Comment: `if (!$('body').css("background").match(/url\(*\.jpg/)) {`

Comment: this seems to be working if (!$('body').css("background").match(/url\(*\.jpg/)) { but it does it even on pages that have a background image and not only pages that the URL is empty

Comment: So i think also my issue is i am trying to fetch the CSS for body and then if the URL is empty do the rest.

Comment: @Aaron check out updated answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

> Updated! Now complete with a `STOP`button!

```js
if (!window.hasOwnProperty('bgChanger')) {
 window.bgChanger = {
  baseHref: 'http://stage.houstonian.com/resources/1/BG_Images/',
  imgArray: ['exterior.jpg', 'chairs.jpg', 'entrance-logo.jpg'],
  secs: 2,  //  changed seconds to 2 just for quick show
  tmr: void 0,
  init: function() {
   bgChanger.setBGImg();
   bgChanger.sequencer();
        },
  getNextImgPath: function() { // will get random image path
   return this.baseHref + this.imgArray[~~(Math.random() * (this.imgArray.length - 0))];
  },
  sequencer: function() {
   if (this.tmr) clearTimeout(this.tmr);
   this.tmr = setTimeout(this.init, this.secs*1e3);
  },
  setBGImg: function() {
   var imgPath = this.getNextImgPath(),
    current = $('body').css('backgroundImage');
   // this while statement helps ensure a different image everytime
   while (current.match(imgPath)) imgPath = this.getNextImgPath();
   $('body').css('backgroundImage', 'url('+imgPath+')');
  },
  stop: function() { if (this.tmr) clearTimeout(this.tmr); }
 }
 // preloader
 bgChanger.imgArray.forEach(function(img) { new Image().src=bgChanger.baseHref+img;  });
}


$(function() {
 if (!$('body').css("background-image").match(/url\(.*(gif|jpg|jpeg|tiff|png)/i)) bgChanger.init();
 
 $('button').click(function(e) {
  if ($(this).text() == 'STOP') {
   $(this).text('GO');
   bgChanger.stop();
  }
  else {
   $(this).text('STOP');
   bgChanger.init();
  }
 });
 
})
```

```css
html, body { height: 100%; width: 100%; }
body {
  background-color: transparent;
  background: url() no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}

table { height: 100%; width: 100%; }
th { height: 100%; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; }
button { font-size: 2em; padding: 1em 1.5em; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table><tr><th><button>STOP</button></th></tr></table>
```

Comment: @Aaron just fyi, since your comment, i made a small change to it, might want to update

Comment: does having this /url\(*.jpg/ mean that if the url is empty it will run and if it has something in the url () it wont?

Comment: @Aaron it means the `background-image` MUST HAVE `url([anything-here].jpg)` you'll want to change it a little if not all your bg images are `jpg`s

Comment: The system renders the css like so background: url([%MEDIA_URL%]) no-repeat center center fixed; and if they do not put an image it renders background: url() no-repeat center center fixed; so we would then want your AWESOME code to run.

Comment: @Aaron I changed my answer to be more encompassing of different image types and to account for upper or lower case

Comment: So i think this is oposite...it runs if there is an image in the background css url and we want it to run if there is no image in the background url css

Comment: @Aaron yeah sorry, regex is a little to play with. I fixed it with this `/url\(.*(gif|jpg|jpeg|tiff|png)/i` FYI: it's fixed in the answer too

Comment: Awesome! ok let me test and one last question...We do not use background-image we use background. will this still work to look if URL is () and then execute?

Comment: @Aaron yes. The problem with your previous code, if you replace just `background`, then you're replacing everything, including your position settings and such. by using `background-image`, we're focusing on just that part, so the rest of your original css for `background` is not overwritten.